# Wordpress Loop - Next 3 Posts

Tags: posts, loop

Hoping someone here can lend me some advice or point me in the right direction.

I have a working Wordpress php function where I can get the next 2 posts in the loop of the current post within a post type and also:

- If the current post is second to last in post type -> display the last post of post type and the first post of the post type.
- If the current post is the last post in the post type -> display the first and second posts.

Example 1:

- Post #1
- Post #2
- Post #3
- Post #4
- Post #5 - viewing this post -> display Post #6 and #1
- Post #6

Example 2:

- Post #1
- Post #2
- Post #4
- Post #5
- Post #6 - viewing this post -> display Post #1 and #2

Here's the function used to achieve the above:

```
function get_post_items($post_item) {
 $post_args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby'        => 'date'        
 );

 $posts_query = new WP_Query( $post_args ); 
 $post_items = array();

 while ($posts_query->have_posts()) {
  $posts_query->the_post();
  $post_items[get_the_ID()] = array(
   'post_link'  => get_the_permalink(),
   'post_title' => get_the_title(),
   'post_img'   => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
   'post_date'  => get_the_date( 'F Y')            
  );
 }
 wp_reset_query();
    
 $post_key = array_search($post_item, array_keys($post_items));
 $posts_length = count($post_items) - 1;
    
 if ( $post_key + 1 < $posts_length ) {
  return array_slice($post_items, $post_key + 1, 2);        
 } elseif ( $post_key + 1 == $posts_length) {               
  $other_posts = array();
  array_push($other_posts, end($post_items), reset($post_items));
  return $other_posts;
 } else {   
  return array_slice($post_items, 0, 2);    
 }
}
```

I now want to display the next 3 posts rather than the next 2 within a post type using the same function.

I can display 3 posts by changing the 2 in `return array_slice($post_items, $post_key + 1, 2)` to `return array_slice($post_items, $post_key + 1, 3)` and `return array_slice($post_items, 0, 2); to return array_slice($post_items, 0, 3);`

I just can't seem to get the if/else conditions to working correctly when viewing the second to last post to show the last post and the first and second posts in post type.

Example 1:

- Post #1
- Post #2
- Post #3
- Post #4
- Post #5 - viewing this post -> display Post #6, #1 and #2
- Post #6

Example 2:

- Post #1
- Post #2
- Post #4
- Post #5
- Post #6 - viewing this post -> display Post #1, #2 and #3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,